# Is it possible to evenly distribute buttons across the width of an android RELATIVE LAYOUT

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Simple Ask

Is it possible to evenly distribute buttons across the width of an android RELATIVE LAYOUT?

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/menu" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button android:layout_height="30dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="aaaaaaa" android:id="@+id/aaaa"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_height="30dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="bbbbbbb" android:id="@+id/bbbbb"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:textStyle="bold"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_height="30dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="cccccccc" android:id="@+id/cccccc"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:textStyle="bold"></Button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about throwing a LinearLayout inside your RelativeLayout, and adding the Buttons inside the LinearLayout (all of the buttons should have the same layout_weight).

Comment: what if I dont wanna use linearlayout for this>

Answer (score 2):

The only way that I know of is to put them in a `LinearLayout` and set the weight.